# Returning Parameters and Using Them in Other Functions

Tags: c++, function

I'm trying to return a value from a function, the function has a parameter and I just don't know how to go about getting these values. I'm aware that I may have done some of the code wrong and that is why I am here.

Here is the code:

```
    // ask user if male or female
// complete calculations depending on result 
// ask user for: weight in lbs, height in inches and age. 

#include <iostream>

// function for users height in inches
double usersHeight(double height)
{
    return height; 
}

//function for users age
int usersAge(int age)
{
    return age; 
}

// function for users weight in lbs
double usersWeight(double weight)
{
    return weight;
}

// mens bmr (basal metabolic rate)
double calculateBmrForMen()
{
    // return calculations
    // Men: BMR = 66 + (6.23 x weight in pounds) + (12.7 x height in inches) - (6.8 x age in years)
    double BMR = 66 + (6.23 * usersWeight(weight/*how do I get user input and here without causing any errors?*/)) 
                    + (12.7 * usersHeight(height/* and here*/))
                    - (6.8 * usersAge(age/*and here*/));
    return BMR; 
}

// womens bmr
double calculateBmrForWomen()
{
    // return calculations
    // Women: BMR = 655 + (4.35 x weight in pounds) + (4.7 x height in inches) - (4.7 x age in years)

    double BMR = 655 + (4.35 * usersWeight()) + (4.7 * usersHeight()) - (4.7 * usersAge());
    return BMR; 
}

int main()
{
    /*char a; 

    std::cout << "Are you Male or Female: " << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Press M if Male\nPress F if female" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> a; 

    if (a == 'm') 
    {
        calculateBmrForMen(); 
    }
    else if (a == 'f')
    {
        calculateBmrForWomen(); 
    }*/

    std::cin.get(); 
    std::cin.clear();
}
```

Comment: `weight/*how do I get user input and here without causing any errors?*/)` Use a local variable named `weight` and `std::cin` maybe?

Comment: I don't know why you received -4 here, and whilst it would be nice for people to declare their DVs we do allow anonymous voting, so we'll have to guess. It is possibly that there is no indication of what debugging you have done, or what the problem is exactly. If you can be more specific in future, that often helps. Also, it is a good idea to refrain from adding voting commentary in posts, as that can paradoxically encourage more DVs! HTH.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at how you are using these functions, I am guessing that you would like to prompt the user to input the age of the user in the function `userAge` and return that value to the calling function.

If that is what you would like to do ...

Here's what your function should look like.

```
int usersAge()
{
    int age;
    std::cout << "Please enter age: ";
    std::cin >> age;

    // If the user entered incorrect data, try again.
    if ( !std::cin )
    {
       std::cout << "Unable to read age. Try again.\n";
       std::cin.clear();
       std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
       return userAge();
    }

    return age; 
}
```

Make sure to add

```
#include <limits>
```

to be able to use `std::numeric_limits`.

Make similar changes for the other functions.

Comment: Thank you for your response. If you wouldn't mind, would you be able to explain how the "(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');" works? I've never seen that before, if not, that's fine. 

Kind regards

Comment: @ShaneLee. You can find lot of answers in SO that use `istream::ignore`. You can see more details at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore.

Answer (score 0):

Please modify your code as follows; 
Hope this helps.

```
double usersHeight()
{
    double height;
    cout << "Ënter Height..." << endl;
    cin >> height; 
    return height;
}

//function for users age
int usersAge()
{
    int age;
    cout << "Ënter age..." << endl;
    cin >> age; 
    return age;
}

// function for users weight in lbs
double usersWeight()
{
    double weight;
    cout << "Ënter weight..." << endl;
    cin >> weight; 
    return weight;
}


double calculateBmrForMen()
{
    // return calculations
    // Men: BMR = 66 + (6.23 x weight in pounds) + (12.7 x height in inches) - (6.8 x age in years)
    double BMR = 66 + (6.23 * usersWeight()) 
                    + (12.7 * usersHeight())
                    - (6.8 * usersAge());
    return BMR; 
}

// womens bmr
double calculateBmrForWomen()
{
    // return calculations
    // Women: BMR = 655 + (4.35 x weight in pounds) + (4.7 x height in inches) - (4.7 x age in years)

    double BMR = 655 + (4.35 * usersWeight()) + (4.7 * usersHeight()) - (4.7 * usersAge());
    return BMR; 
}

int main()
{
    char a; 
    double BMI;
    std::cout << "Are you Male or Female: " << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Press M if Male\nPress F if female" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> a; 
    if (a == 'm') 
    {
        BMI = calculateBmrForMen(); 
    }
    else if (a == 'f')
    {
        BMI = calculateBmrForWomen(); 
    }

    cout << "The BMI is..."<< BMI << endl;
    std::cin.get(); 
    std::cin.clear();
}
```